# JavaScript Help - With Page event/Var

Tags: java, javascript, html, session, session-variables

Can anyone help me with the following?

I have a navigation bar, for example:

Step_1.html  - Step_2.html - Step_3.html - Step_4.html

i would like the links for the next two steps ie 3 and 4 to be disabled.

Then when they go to step 2 only step 4 to be disabled.

(but heres the problem when i get to say Step_4.html and want to go back to Step_2.html, i want to be able to click straight back to Step_4.html as i have been through all the steps already so i would like it to now not be disabled in my navigation bar)

I would only like to use java-script if possible !

Page 1 looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sessvars.js"></script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>p4</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>Page 1</p>
<p><a href="p2.html">Page 2</a></p>
<p>Page 3</p>
<p>Page 4</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Page 2 like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sessvars.js"></script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>p4</title>
</head>

<body>
<p><a href="p1.html">Page 1</a></p>
<p>Page 2</p>
<p><a href="p3.html">Page 3</a></p>
<p>Page 4</p>
</body>
</html>
```

page 3 like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sessvars.js"></script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>p4</title>
</head>

<body>
<p><a href="p1.html">Page 1</a></p>
<p><a href="p2.html">Page 2</a></p>
<p>Page 3</p>
<p><a href="p4.html">Page 4</a></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

page 4 like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sessvars.js"></script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>p4</title>
</head>

<body>
<p><a href="p1.html">Page 1</a></p>
<p><a href="p2.html">Page 2</a></p>
<p><a href="p3.html">Page 3</a></p>
<p>Page 4</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you please post code? There are to many possibilities how you did it till you came into your problem. Thought about using a navigation library?

Comment: work on your question a bit. Like @Neysor said, post some sample html code along with it so that people can understand your requirement better

Comment: Ma9ic wants to make it so you can't skip a step, but if you back up a step you won't be forbidden from viewing the step you already got to.

Comment: GoldenNewby has it spot on :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to want to use cookies created in javascript to store the state of where they are in the step-by-step process.

Check out http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Make a cookie that stores the highest step the user has gotten to. Check the value of this on each page, and if the page they are on is "higher" (step 4 > step 3), overwrite the cookie with this new value. That way, if they back up to step 1 from step 4, they will still have "access" to step 4.